# Python:List Addition

Tags: python, list, addition

I have two lists like below.i am getting this from database

```
EmpID = Assign.objects.select_related().filter(pName=selProject).filter()
    .order_by('laEmpNum').values_list('laEmpNum', flat=True)

TotDur = Assign.objects.select_related().filter(pName=selProject).order_by('laEmpNum')
    .values_list('duration', flat=True)

EmpID = [u'1046', u'1046', u'1046', u'8008', u'8008', u'8011'] 

TotDur = [0.0, 2.0, 2.5, 0.0, 2.7, 1.2]
```

If EmpIDs are same then corresponding values in TotDur should collect and add(sum).

```
ResOne = 0.0 + 2.0 + 2.5    i.e 4.5
ResTwo = 0.0+2.7            i.e 2.7
ResThr = 1.2                i.e 1.2
```

How to do this in Python.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the elements are in order as you have shown in your example, you can use [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby)

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter
[(k , sum(e for _,e in v)) for k,v in groupby(zip(EmpID, TotDur), itemgetter(0))]
[(u'1046', 4.5), (u'8008', 2.7), (u'8011', 1.2)]
```

infact you don't need to create two separate list and zip it later

```
Emp_TotDur = Assign.objects.select_related().filter(pName=selProject).filter()
    .order_by('laEmpNum').values_list('laEmpNum', 'duration')

[(k , sum(e for _,e in v)) for k,v in groupby(Emp_TotDur, itemgetter(0))]
```

Answer (score 3):

[`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) is a good data structure to use, for `int` fields it assumes the value `0` for new keys, and allows for easy bucket collection:

```
from collections import defaultdict
d = defaultdict(int)
for i, j in zip(EmpID, TotDur):
    d[i] += j
print d # defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'8008': 2.7, u'1046': 4.5, u'8011': 1.2})
```

Comment: How's this different from my answer?

Comment: It isn't, I didn't notice yours until I posted mine ;)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Why does it need to be different? It does explain the `int` behaviour explicitly, which I found useful.

Answer (score 2):

you can use [`defaultdict`](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/collections#collections.defaultdict):

```
In [60]: from collections import *

In [61]: EmpID = [u'1046', u'1046', u'1046', u'8008', u'8008', u'8011']

In [62]: TotDur = [0.0, 2.0, 2.5, 0.0, 2.7, 1.2]

In [63]: d=defaultdict(int)

In [64]: for x,y in zip(EmpID,TotDur):
    d[x]+=y
   ....:     

In [65]: d
Out[65]: defaultdict(<type 'int'>, {u'8008': 2.7, u'1046': 4.5, u'8011': 1.2})
```

or simply `dict`:

```
In [70]: d=dict()

In [71]: for x,y in zip(EmpID,TotDur):
    d[x]=d.get(x,0)+y
   ....:     

In [72]: d
Out[72]: {u'1046': 4.5, u'8008': 2.7, u'8011': 1.2}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this

```
l1 = [1,1,2,3,3]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5]
last_val=l1[0]
sum=0
list=[]
for pair in zip(l1,l2): 
    if pair[0]!=last_val:
        print(sum)
        list.append(sum)
        sum=0
    last_val=pair[0]
    sum+=pair[1]
list.append(sum)
print(list)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can [zip](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) the two lists, which pairs the elements of the first to the elements of the second into tuples. Then loop over them and use the first part of the tuple as keys in a dictionary:

```
EmpID = [u'1046', u'1046', u'1046', u'8008', u'8008', u'8011']
TotDur = [0.0, 2.0, 2.5, 0.0, 2.7, 1.2]
Result = {}

for (key, value) in zip(EmpID, TotDur):
    if not key in Result:
        Result[key] = value
    else:
        Result[key] += value

# Print the result
for (key, value) in Result.items():
    print key, value
```

You may want to use an [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) if you want to preserve the order of the Emps

Answer (score 0):

Try this, it puts sum of all corresponding id's values to a list, later you can access the list with empId and see its sum.

```
finalList = []
lastEmpId

for index, emp in enumarate(EmdIP):
    if lastEmpId == emp:
        finalList[lastEmpId] += TotDur[index]
    else:
        finalList[lastEmpId] = TotDur[index]
    lastEmpId = emp;

print finalList
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    python 3.2
    res=[]
    for i in set(ID):
         b=[]
         for x,y in enumerate(ID):
              if i==y: b.append(T[x])
    res.append(sum(b))
```